# Jquery/ajax get object from a class and use it in a textbox in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working on a asp.net mv3 application.

In a helper class I have a method that return an object of a person based on his ID

```
public Person GetPersonByID(string id)
{
    // I get the person from a list with the given ID and return it
}
```

In a view I need to create a jquery or javascript function that can call the `GetPersonByID`

```
function getPerson(id) {
    //I need to get the person object by calling the GetPersonByID from the C# 
    //helper class and put the values Person.FirstName and Person.LastName in 
    //Textboxes on my page
}
```

how can I do that?

Can this be done by using and ajax call?

```
    $.ajax({
            type:
            url:
            success:
            }
        });
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Javascript or jQuery for that matter doesn't know what a `method` means. jQuery doesn't know what C# is. jQuery doesn't know what ASP.NET MVC is. jQuery doesn't know what the `Person` .NET class means. jQuery doesn't know what a .NET class means.

jQuery is a javascript framework which (among many other things) could be used to send AJAX requests to a server side script.

In ASP.NET MVC those server side scripts are called **controller actions**. In Java those are called servlets. In PHP - PHP scripts. And so on...

So you could write a controller action that could be queried using AJAX and which will return a JSON serialized instance of the `Person` class:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string id)
{
    var person = Something.GetPersonByID(id);
    return Json(person, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then:

```
function getPerson(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "SomeController")',
        type: 'GET',
        // we set cache: false because GET requests are often cached by browsers
        // IE is particularly aggressive in that respect
        cache: false,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(person) {
            $('#FirstName').val(person.FirstName);
            $('#LastName').val(person.LastName);
        }
    });
}
```

This obviously assumes that your Person class has `FirstName` and `LastName` properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to learn this as I am doing something very similar. In your `$.ajax` where does the value for the `id` string get set? That will be what gets passed into the `ActionResult` method correct? Also, what if my ActionResult method does not have or does not require an input parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can!  All you need to do in your server-side code, specifically in the controller, is return the Person serialized as a JSON object, like so:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPersonByID(string id)
{
    return Json(person);
}

Then in your AJAX,

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //...
            },
            success: function (result) {
                // result.FirstName
            }
        });
```